# Organize scale of x axis of time series graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here I have data that looks like this:

```
# Data
df <- data.frame("Hospital" = c("Buge Hospital", "Buge Hospital", "Greta Hospital", "Greta Hospital",
                                "Makor Hospital", "Makor Hospital"),
                 "Period" = c("Jul-18","Aug-18", "Jul-19","Aug-19", "Jul-20","Aug-20"),
                 "Medical admissions" = c(12,56,0,40,5,56),
                 "Surgical admissions" = c(10,2,0,50,20,56),
                 "Inpatient admissions" = c(9,5,6,0,60,96))
```

Now this data has a column called period which is monthy data for different years, 2018,2019 and 2020

if I plot this data, here is how it looks

```
library(ggplot2
# Melt data into long format
df2 <- melt(data = df,
                id.vars = c("Hospital","Period"), 
                measure.vars = names(df[3:5]))

# Stacked barplot
ggplot( df2, aes(x = Period, y = value, fill = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle(unique(df2$Hospital))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = %Y)+
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of People", fill = "Type")
```

It plots well but the x axis is not organized in ascending order, I have tried to use **scale_x_date** function but still the plot is the same. What I want is months for the year 2018 to start, then followed with months for 2019 and 2020. I mean x axis to be organized in ascending order based on years like this
*Aug-18*, *Jul-18*, *Aug-19*,*Jul-19*, *Aug-20,Jul-20*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, you need to convert your Period in a date format.

For example, you can use `parse_date` function from `lubridate` package:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Date = parse_date(as.character(Period), format = "%b-%y")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Medical.admissions:Inpatient.admissions, names_to = "Var", values_to = "Val")

# A tibble: 18 x 5
   Hospital       Period Date       Var                    Val
   <fct>          <fct>  <date>     <chr>                <dbl>
 1 Buge Hospital  Jul-18 2018-07-01 Medical.admissions      12
 2 Buge Hospital  Jul-18 2018-07-01 Surgical.admissions     10
 3 Buge Hospital  Jul-18 2018-07-01 Inpatient.admissions     9
 4 Buge Hospital  Aug-18 2018-08-01 Medical.admissions      56
 5 Buge Hospital  Aug-18 2018-08-01 Surgical.admissions      2
 6 Buge Hospital  Aug-18 2018-08-01 Inpatient.admissions     5
 7 Greta Hospital Jul-19 2019-07-01 Medical.admissions       0
 8 Greta Hospital Jul-19 2019-07-01 Surgical.admissions      0
 9 Greta Hospital Jul-19 2019-07-01 Inpatient.admissions     6
10 Greta Hospital Aug-19 2019-08-01 Medical.admissions      40
11 Greta Hospital Aug-19 2019-08-01 Surgical.admissions     50
12 Greta Hospital Aug-19 2019-08-01 Inpatient.admissions     0
13 Makor Hospital Jul-20 2020-07-01 Medical.admissions       5
14 Makor Hospital Jul-20 2020-07-01 Surgical.admissions     20
15 Makor Hospital Jul-20 2020-07-01 Inpatient.admissions    60
16 Makor Hospital Aug-20 2020-08-01 Medical.admissions      56
17 Makor Hospital Aug-20 2020-08-01 Surgical.admissions     56
18 Makor Hospital Aug-20 2020-08-01 Inpatient.admissions    96
```

So, then, you can use `scale_x_date` to set appropriate labeling option on your x axis:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% mutate(Date = parse_date(as.character(Period), format = "%b-%y")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Medical.admissions:Inpatient.admissions, names_to = "Var", values_to = "Val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Val, fill= Var, group = Var))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", date_labels = "%b %Y")+
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of People", fill = "Type")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**EDIT: Using `lubridate v1.7.8**

On `lubridate` version 1.7.8, `parse_date` does not exist anymore. You will have to replace it by `parse_date_time` as follow:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Date = ymd(parse_date_time2(as.character(Period), orders = "%b-%y"))) %>% ....
```

Comment: Is it possible to have hidden months being displayed?

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Its perfect. Thank you